# ¿Cómo puedo convertir esta función grande en dos funciones, me pueden dar ideas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Este programa te dice cuanto te tomara en pagar un préstamo,(te pide tasa de interés anual,cuanto vas a pedir prestado y cuanto vas a pagar mensualmente )

```
def calcula_deuda():
      #esta parte consige variables      
      dinero_prestado=int(input('cuanto dinero quieres pedir prestado??'))
      porcentaje_anual = int(input('cual es el porcentaje anual expresado en porcentaje'))/100
      pago_mensual=int(input('cual es el pago mensual que haras?'))
      porcentaje_mensual = porcentaje_anual/12

      #esta parte de abajo calcula el primer mes
      P_interes_mensual = dinero_prestado * porcentaje_mensual  
      nuevo_balance = dinero_prestado + P_interes_mensual - pago_mensual  
      mes=0
      total=0
      la_deuda = True 

      #esta parte de abajo te dice si pagas suficiente dinero al mes
      if P_interes_mensual > pago_mensual : 
        print('debes hacer pagos de por lo menos $',format(total + P_interes_mensual + 1, '.2f'))
        print('por que tu interes mensual es $',format(total + P_interes_mensual, '.2f'))

      #esta parte hace los calculos para el segundo mes hasta el ultimo
      while la_deuda:
        if nuevo_balance > 0:
          interes_mensual = nuevo_balance * porcentaje_mensual 
          nuevo_balance = nuevo_balance + interes_mensual - pago_mensual 
          mes=mes+1
          total = total + interes_mensual
        else:
          la_deuda = False  

      #esta parte te da los resultados de los calculos
      pago_final = pago_mensual + nuevo_balance
      print('la deuda se pagara en', mes+1,'meses')
      print('tu pago final sera de $',format(pago_final,'.2f'))  
      print('el monto de interes que pagras en todo este tiempo es $',format(total+P_interes_mensual,'.2f'))

calcula_deuda()
```

Comment: Sin más información yo diría que un esquema lógico sería dividirlo aproximadamente por donde tienes comentarios. De hecho, un comentario que dice "Esto hace tal cosa" está en el fondo definiendo una función que podría llamarse `tal_cosa`. Así podrías tener como funciones `pedir_datos()`,  `calcular_primer_mes()`,  `calcular_resto_meses()` y `mostrar_resultados()`. Si no quieres tantas funciones puedes agrupar los cálculos del primer y resto de meses en una sola función.

Comment: Yo personalmente haría 3 funciones: la primera para solicitar los datos que los pasaría a la segunda para hacer el cálculo y ésta a se los pasaría a la tercera para mostrarlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"""
Una función para capturar los datos y otra para calcularlos.
Agregué un diccionario para que el código no perdiera legibilidad.

"""
def obtener_datos():
    datos = {}
    #esta parte consige variables      
    datos["dinero_prestado"] =int(input('¿Cuánto dinero quieres pedir prestado? '))
    datos["porcentaje_anual"] = int(input('¿Cuál es el porcentaje anual expresado en porcentaje? '))/100
    datos["pago_mensual"] = int(input('¿Cuál es el pago mesual que harás? '))
    datos["porcentaje_mensual"] = datos["porcentaje_anual"]/12
    return datos

def calcula_deuda(valores):
    #esta parte de abajo calcula el primer mes
    P_interes_mensual = valores["dinero_prestado"] * valores["porcentaje_mensual"] 
    nuevo_balance = valores["dinero_prestado"] + P_interes_mensual - valores["pago_mensual"]
    mes=0
    total=0
    la_deuda = True 

    #esta parte de abajo te dice si pagas suficiente dinero al mes
    if P_interes_mensual > valores["pago_mensual"] : 
        print('Debes hacer pagos de por lo menos $',format(total + P_interes_mensual + 1, '.2f'))
        print('Porque tu interés mensual es $',format(total + P_interes_mensual, '.2f'))

    #esta parte hace los calculos para el segundo mes hasta el ultimo
    while la_deuda:
        if nuevo_balance > 0:
            interes_mensual = nuevo_balance * valores["porcentaje_mensual"] 
            nuevo_balance = nuevo_balance + interes_mensual - valores["pago_mensual"]
            mes=mes+1
            total = total + interes_mensual
        else:
            la_deuda = False  

    #esta parte te da los resultados de los calculos
    pago_final = valores["pago_mensual"] + nuevo_balance
    print('La deuda se pagará en', mes+1,'meses.')
    print('Tu pago final será de $',format(pago_final,'.2f'))  
    print('El monto de interés que pagarás en todo este tiempo es $',format(total+P_interes_mensual,'.2f'))

datos_ingresados = obtener_datos()
calcula_deuda(datos_ingresados)
```